# Inserting all rows from subquery using asubselect with an alias and sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm having an issue insert to a table using a subquery and subselect on a table that has a sequence.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table
     (sequence_id,
     product_code,
     product_status)
 SELECT 
     sequence_id.NEXTVAL,
     alias_table.* from (SELECT
     product_code, 
     product_status,
 FROM products
 WHERE product_code = '123456') alias_table;
```

The main issue I'm having is with the sequence because this query will return multiple rows and I need the sequence to advance.  Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running your simplified code? It works for me, as does @koljaTM's code, as does my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This (I didn't test it)

```
INSERT INTO my_table
 (sequence_id,
 product_code,
 product_status)
 SELECT 
     sequence_id.NEXTVAL,
     alias_table.product_code,
     alias_table.product_status
 from (SELECT
           product_code, 
           product_status
       FROM products
       WHERE product_code = '123456') alias_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT ...
SELECT 
 sequence_id.NEXTVAL,
 product_code, 
 product_status
FROM products
WHERE product_code = '123456';
```

Comment: I've tried this method originally and it gives me an ORA-02287 error "Sequence number not allowed here'.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger to insert the next sequence value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_schema.my_table_ins_trg
   BEFORE INSERT ON my_schema.my_table FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (New.ID IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT my_schema.sequence_id.Nextval INTO :New.ID FROM dual;
END;
```

Then you can remove the sequence from your insert query:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table
     (product_code,
      product_status)
 SELECT alias_table.* FROM (SELECT product_code, product_status
                              FROM products
                             WHERE product_code = '123456') alias_table;
```

Comment: We were actually going to use a trigger but we didn't want to add another thing for our DBA's to maintain.  I actually used the method suggested by T.S. below.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user2600900 Glad you found a solution. :)